# Add class and remove class not work in single statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#p1").addClass("size").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000).removeClass("size");
        /* p1 is a id of element, i want to add size class after that to remove it */
    });
```

Comment: so you want to click on the button, add a class, slide up, then slide down and remove the class all in one go?

Comment: I think what you 're looking for is an ' animate ' function , you can try this one :

Comment: http://devdocs.io/jquery/animate

Comment: Abraham, man you there? `:)`

Comment: hello praveen, i m here !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the second statement as a callback function on the `slideDown()`:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#p1").addClass("size").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000, function () {
      $(this).removeClass("size");
    });
});
```

Or still better, you need to use the callback function of the `slideUp` also!

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#p1").addClass("size").slideUp(2000, function () {
        // Execute this after 2 seconds of slideUp animation.
        $(this).slideDown(2000, function () {
            // Execute this after 2 seconds of slideDown animation.
            $(this).removeClass("size");
        });
    });
});
```

Because they are not supposed to happen in parallel, but in a sequential order, after each has been finished.

Comment: Any animate method as `slideUp()/slideDown()` use fx queue so it never run in parallel. Your first snippet is enough and more readable :)

Comment: @A.Wolff First is kinda wrong. But the second one is the right one. Oh wait, so you mean to say both do the same?

Comment: Ya both do the same, the second one is the explicit version but in detriment of readability imho

Comment: @A.Wolff Okay then. I am leaving both of them here so that the OP can choose what best suits for him. But still lemme check it once. `:)` May be just because it is executing on the same element it is queued, is it?

Comment: Ya, it uses fx queue in jQuery

Comment: Was creating a jsfiddle but then saw you had the same answer as me so :)

Comment: As a side note, to handle multiple click, you should use: `$('#p1').stop()...`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Just `stop()`, `stop(true, true)` (which in this case is the same as just `stop(true)`) will complete any previous animation, i'm guess not really expected behaviour regarding displayed element

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are adding and removing fine, but it is happening instantly. You need to put some delay in it.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#p1").addClass("size").slideUp(2000, function(){$(this).slideDown(2000 ,function(){ $(this).removeClass("size")})});
    /* p1 is a id of element, i want to add size class after that to remove it */
});
```